# Ignore Specific Computer Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need a way to remove my own traffic and interaction from my Google Analytics.

I know of all the IP and cookie based solutions but IPs can change and cookies can be erased.

One thing I did think of is that I'm always logged into my Google account and I'm always using Chrome. Is there any way to use this to my advantage? It would be really nice if I could just ignore based on my Google Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Browser Extensions**

Use a browser extension to prevent you from being tracked on analytics. I use the [Block Yourself From Analytics](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-yourself-from-analy/fadgflmigmogfionelcpalhohefbnehm?utm_source=gmail) extensions because it allows you to configure the sites you want to prevent traffic on.

Comment: Why is it that these ideas come to me immediately after I post the question? As this solution never popped up during my Googling I'm going to leave the question and answer here.

Comment: I agree that browser extensions are the way, but I was unsatisfied with the existing Chrome extensions, so I made a new one that keeps a special "developer cookie" set on my machine: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lknhpplgahpbindnnocglcjonpahfikn